# How can an image be set behind a child element and be responsive?

Tags: css

I would like to have an element superimposed on an image, which should responsively adjust to the element's dimensions.

In the example below, the goal is to have `img` completely surround the sibling element. Right now, it only partially covers it:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100">

  <div>
    Content Goes here
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>

</section>
```

I tried adding `background-image` to `section`, but that doesn't seem to work either. Right now my only option is to use media queries and manually adjust the height of `img`, but I was curious if there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: I posted an answer, but am unclear actually why you would want to modify the height of the picture with media queries in order to be responsive? Please explain.

Comment: Technically I am trying to modify the height of the container so that the contents are completely inside.As the screen gets smaller the contents will naturally get smaller, increasing its width. I would like to know how the container can respond to these changes.

Comment: You want the red content block to be entirely on top of the image, so nothing sticks out, and the image needs to preserve its original ratio, or can ratio change?

Comment: Yes, the red block should be entirely inside the boundaries of the image. The ratio of the image can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the image as a background of the section. Please note, that I removed the position absolute of the div element so the section can growth with that element. You can play around with the different background [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) till you get your desired result.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 15px; /* optional padding */
}


div {
  padding: 30px;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <div>
    Content Goes here
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `transform` on the `div`?

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-25px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100">

  <div>
    Content Goes here
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can do it in this way, i feel like usually child element work or inherit the properties of the parent. even in the case of relative and absolute parent child relation, child element stays with the parent even though wherever the parent goes/moves

so, if you want a background image to be superimposed on some element, first of all, may be you have to set the parent element/background image's properties properly and then keep your content inside. if your content is overflowing/larger than background you might have to adjust it manually ( like you said, with media queries ) or you can try in this way.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
          .image-back {
            padding: 30px;
            margin: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1000x100');
            }
          .content {
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <div class="image-back">
          <div class="content">
            <p>Content Goes here</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

here in this case, try to get an image that can contain the size of inner element and its border+padding+etc. and have a look at how it behaves with different screen resolutions.